# How to query all records that don't have a specific association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

If I want a list of all the shops that are open on Sunday, I do

```
Shop.includes(:opening_times).where("opening_times.day =?", 'Sunday')
```

Is there any way to get a list of all the shops that are closed on Sundays? That is, all the shops that are not associated with a record where the day column is 'Sunday'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sun_open = Shop.includes(:opening_times).where("opening times.day = ?", "Sunday").ids;
sunday_closed = Shop.where("id NOT IN (?)", sunday_open);
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea you could so easily have a list of the ids from a db query. That will come in handy in so many situations!

Comment: I get the error "column reference "id" is ambiguous" when using the .ids method, because it's an includes table and it doesn't know whether to take the Shop ids or the OpeningTimes ids. Using `.map(&:id)` instead of `.ids` fixes it.