# How can I query all records that don't have a specific association without loading them all into memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

If I want a list of all the shops that are open on Sunday, I do

```
Shop.includes(:opening_times).where("opening_times.day =?", 'Sunday')
```

Is there any way to get a list of all the shops that are closed on Sundays? That is, all the shops that are not associated with a record where the day column is 'Sunday'?

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028988/how-to-query-all-records-that-dont-have-a-specific-association) and accepted an answer. However, now my database is getting too big to solve this by loading all the open shops into memory first. Is there a way to do this without first getting an array of all the open shops and passing that array back to the database?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but what about `where("opening_times.day != ?", 'Sunday')`?

Comment: @DamienRoche That returns everything that is open any other day than Sunday. For example it would return a shop that is open on both Saturday and Sunday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a more Railsy way, but with a single query (and subquery):

```
Shop.where("shop_id NOT IN (select opening_times.shop_id from opening_times where opening_times.day = 'Sunday')")
```

Or, based on the linked question, you could improve by using `pluck`:

```
shop_ids = Shop.includes(:opening_times).where("opening_times.day = ?", 'Sunday').pluck(:id)
shops = Shop.where("id NOT IN(?)", shop_ids)
```

The current method you're using (`map(&:id)`) is instantiating objects for every row, whereas `pluck(:id)` will perform a `select id` query.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me how to do it in one query. I had to use `shops.id NOT IN` instead of `id NOT IN` to avoid an ambiguous id error. With that change, it works perfectly.

Comment: @lala no problem. Ahh yes, course, I'll update answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

A faster way without `map` would be to pluck the id's instead.

```
open = Shop.includes(:opening_times).where(opening_times: { day: 'Sunday' }).pluck(:id)
closed = Shop.where.not(id: open)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but I'll have a go.

When I need to query for objects that *don't* have an association, I normally created a counter cache for the # of associated objects and query that. So, in the end, your query would look like this:

`Shop.include(:opening_times).where("opening_times.sunday_count", 0)`